# Get Custom attribute from current product in product tabs - Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, content-management-system, product, static-block

I would like to get some custom attributes from the current product in the product tabs (on product page). At the moment, the tabs are populated from cms > static blocks. Is it possible to get the value of those custom product attributes in the block itself? If not, how can i get them to be displayed on relevant tabs.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to display products' attributes in the static block?

Answer (score 0):

non-EAV attributes, must be saved some where in database.
Load it dynamically from there.